# Why google chrome puts arguments into command line?

Tags: google-chrome

When you do a `ps -axwuw` in MacOsX:

`sato            75067   0.0  0.4  3739032  74312   ??  S    12:30PM   0:09.10 /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/Versions/56.0.2924.87/Google Chrome Helper.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome Helper --type=renderer --enable-features=AutofillProfileCleanup<AutofillProfileCleanup,BlockSmallPluginContent<PluginPowerSaverTiny,EnableSyncClientToServerCompression<EnableSyncClientToServerCompression,*ExpectCTReporting<ExpectCTReporting,*NegotiateTLS13<TLS13Negotiation,ParseHTMLOnMainThread<ParseHTMLOnMainThread,*PersistentHistograms<PersistentHistograms,*PointerEvent<PointerEvent,PreferHtmlOverPlugins<Html5ByDefault,SecurityChip<SecurityChip,SecurityWarningIconUpdate<SecurityWarningIconUpdate,SubresourceFilter<SubresourceFilter,*TranslateRankerLogging<TranslateRankerLogging,ViewsSimplifiedFullscreenUI<ViewsSimplifiedFullscreenUI --disable-features=DocumentWriteEvaluator<DisallowFetchForDocWrittenScriptsInMainFrame,SSLPostQuantumExperiment<SSLPostQuantum --force-fieldtrials=*AppBannerTriggering/site-engagement-eager/*AutofillProfileCleanup/Enabled/*CaptivePortalInterstitial/Enabled/*ChromeChannelStable/Enabled/*ChromeSuggestionsTuning/Default/*ClientSideDetectionModel/Model0/*DataReductionProxyUseQuic/Enabled10_NoControl/*DisallowFetchForDocWrittenScriptsInMainFrame/DocumentWriteScriptBlockGroup_20161208_Launch/EnableSyncClientToServerCompression/Enabled/ExpectCTReporting/ExpectCTReportingDisabled/*ExtensionDeveloperModeWarning/Enabled/*ExtensionInstallVerification/Enforce/*Html5ByDefault/SEI_Control/*InstanceID/Enabled/*MarkNonSecureAs/show-non-secure-passwords-cc-ui/*OmniboxBundledExperimentV1/StandardR7/*ParseHTMLOnMainThread/Default/*PasswordBranding/SmartLockBrandingSavePromptOnly/*PasswordGeneration/Disabled/*PasswordManagerSettingsMigration/Enable/*PersistentHistograms/Default/*PluginPowerSaverTiny/Enabled2/*QUIC/EnabledNoId/*ReportCertificateErrors/ShowAndPossiblySend/SHA1IdentityUIWarning/Enabled/SHA1ToolbarUIJanuary2016/Warning/SHA1ToolbarUIJanuary2017/Error/*SSLCommonNameMismatchHandling/Enabled/*SSLPostQuantum/disabled/*SafeBrowsingIncidentReportingService/Default/SafeBrowsingUnverifiedDownloads/DisableByParameterMostSbTypes2/SafeBrowsingV4LocalDatabaseManagerEnabled/Default/*SecurityChip/Enabled/*SecurityWarningIconUpdate/Enabled/SignInPasswordPromo/Enable3/*SiteIsolationExtensions/Enabled_100/*StrictSecureCookies/Enabled/*SubresourceFilter/EnabledForPhishingSites/*TLS13Negotiation/Default/*TranslateRankerLogging/TranslateRankerLoggingDefault/TranslateServerStudy/SmartRendering/*UMA-Dynamic-Uniformity-Trial/Group3/*UMA-Population-Restrict/normal/*UMA-Uniformity-Trial-1-Percent/group_46/*UMA-Uniformity-Trial-10-Percent/group_05/*UMA-Uniformity-Trial-100-Percent/group_01/*UMA-Uniformity-Trial-20-Percent/group_01/*UMA-Uniformity-Trial-5-Percent/group_12/*UMA-Uniformity-Trial-50-Percent/group_01/*WebFontsInterventionV2/Default/ --primordial-pipe-token=F62647FB37B57FE89DE7405D6B963C29 --lang=ja --enable-offline-auto-reload --enable-offline-auto-reload-visible-only --blink-settings=disallowFetchForDocWrittenScriptsInMainFrame=false,disallowFetchForDocWrittenScriptsInMainFrameOnSlowConnections=true --enable-pinch --num-raster-threads=4 --enable-gpu-rasterization --enable-zero-copy --enable-gpu-memory-buffer-compositor-resources --enable-main-frame-before-activation --content-image-texture-target=0,0,3553;0,1,3553;0,2,3553;0,3,3553;0,4,3553;0,5,3553;0,6,3553;0,7,3553;0,8,3553;0,9,3553;0,10,34037;0,11,34037;0,12,34037;0,13,3553;0,14,3553;0,15,3553;1,0,3553;1,1,3553;1,2,3553;1,3,3553;1,4,3553;1,5,3553;1,6,3553;1,7,3553;1,8,3553;1,9,3553;1,10,34037;1,11,34037;1,12,34037;1,13,3553;1,14,3553;1,15,3553;2,0,3553;2,1,3553;2,2,3553;2,3,3553;2,4,3553;2,5,34037;2,6,3553;2,7,3553;2,8,3553;2,9,3553;2,10,3553;2,11,3553;2,12,34037;2,13,3553;2,14,34037;2,15,34037;3,0,3553;3,1,3553;3,2,3553;3,3,3553;3,4,3553;3,5,34037;3,6,3553;3,7,3553;3,8,3553;3,9,3553;3,10,3553;3,11,3553;3,12,34037;3,13,3553;3,14,34037;3,15,34037 --service-request-channel-token=F62647FB37B57FE89DE7405D6B963C29 --renderer-client-id=1428`

While other process is more clean:

`sato             74709   0.0  0.4  2777760  66148   ??  S    12:27PM   0:01.92 /Applications/Preview.app/Contents/MacOS/Preview -psn_0_39540147`

Is it possible to make chrome output little info when ps?